# Fetch records from table

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am working on chat app. I stored all msg into db, but could not fetch and show admin msg which send in reply to person after person 1 send msg to admin.

```php
$email = $_GET["q"];
     if($email== "Admin@gmail.com")
     {
         $sql = "SELECT *, date_format(chatdate,'%d-%m-%Y %r') as cdt from chat order by username AND ID";
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM (" . $sql . ") as ch order by ID";
     $result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

     // Update Row Information
     $msg="<table border='0' style='font-size: 10pt; color: blue; font-family: verdana, arial;'>";
     while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
     {
           $msg = $msg . "<tr><td>" . $line["cdt"] . "&nbsp;</td>" .
                "<td>" . $line["username"] . ":&nbsp;</td>" .
                "<td>" . $line["msg"] . "</td></tr>";
     }
     $msg=$msg . "</table>";

     echo $msg;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply multiple `order by` in filed  using  `comma`

so instead of

```
order by username AND ID
```

Use

```
 order by username,ID
```

Also stop using mysql it is deprecated. You can use `mysqli or pdo`

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things I can see wrong with your code and the first is that I cannot understand at all why you have to select statements (I can't see any reason for them at all) plus you need to separate order by declarations with a comma, not the word AND. You are also concatenating your $msg variable incorrectly. So try this. And, I am not sure if it an error in your copying and pasting but you are also missing the closing curly bracket for your if statement.

```
$email = $_GET["q"];
 if($email== "Admin@gmail.com")
 {
     $sql = "SELECT *, date_format(chatdate,'%d-%m-%Y %r') as cdt from chat order by username, ID";

 $result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

 // Update Row Information
 $msg="<table border='0' style='font-size: 10pt; color: blue; font-family: verdana, arial;'>";
 while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
 {
       $msg .= "<tr><td>" . $line["cdt"] . "&nbsp;</td>" .
            "<td>" . $line["username"] . ":&nbsp;</td>" .
            "<td>" . $line["msg"] . "</td></tr>";
 }
 $msg .= "</table>";

 echo $msg;
```

}

Comment: And as Saty has said, you really should be using mysqli or PDO nowawadays